# Magento 2.1: Order of the columns in BackOffice grid

Tags: magento2, backend, magento-2.1, uicomponent

I just created a grid in the backoffice to list elements of custom tables of the database.

For two of them, the checkbox is the first column, but the last one, the checkbox is juste before the "Action" column, at the right end.

I checked my xml files, they have the same configuration. I try to use the balise sortOrder, like in a core ui file, but without success

```
selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
```

Does anybody know how to define the order of the columns?